# Using an IF statement in a HTACCESS ReWrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the above i have in my htacces file which rewrites `directory/page` to `index.php?id=directory/page`

thats working fine.

I also want to be able to add the following to it:

`domain.com/sections/page` rewrites to `index.php?section=1&id=page`

`domain.com/sections/page2` rewrites to `index.php?section=1&id=page2`

`domain.com/page` rewrites to `index.php?id=page`

the ID is going to be different for each page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take a look at [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directives.

That's a sample `.htaccess` based on your edit.

```
RewriteEngine On

# This will process the /sections/(.*) requests, ?section=1 will be appended to query string    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sections\/(.*)?$ index.php?section=1&id=$1 [L,QSA]

# This will process the other requests, as it does now.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: how about if the 'sections' is not there?

Comment: You can think about `RewriteCond` as if-statement... So, if RewriteCond match `/sections/page` pattern it will execute `RewriteRule` associated with it. You can create another `RewriteCond` to handle other case(s).

Comment: but surely the RewriteRule is going to always add sections=1 in ?

Comment: Yes, it will be added as `GET` parameter.

Comment: thats right, thats what i want but not if the URL does not contain /sections/ after the domain name

Comment: Yes, it will append that parameter to URI **only if** `/sections/page` is matched.

Comment: so i could use my line of code then put your underneath?

Comment: or would it all be in one rewrite rule?

Comment: You can put that piece of code above your current `RewriteRule` and it should works.

Comment: ok, but the ID is not always going to be 'page' so shall i do the cond as '^/sections/(.*)/?$' then the rule as 'index.php?sections=1&page=$1'

Comment: check my update, ive tried to make it a little clearer